# Magento2: Slow Catalog Pages Loadtime

Tags: magento2, performance, html, optimization

I have a website built on the top of magento 2, the problem is when I go to any of the catalog pages, the html takes significant time to load for the first time, as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

when I load the page for the second time the load time drop significantly

[image]

I've gone the webserver (nginx) setup and configurations and made sure it is not causing this.

Also, I've checked the database and made sure there is no queries that is taking that much time while the html page is loading.

Moreover, I've gone through the servers' resources and nothing being maxed out during the load time (CPU & RAM)

What does cause this issue? is it something within magento itself?

Answer (score 0):

there are two parts for a site speed:

1. Server response time : here if you use Varnish and make sure no blocks have cache set as false then your server response time will be pretty good.
2. page and its related assets download time : Here css,JS,fonts and images might take time to be downloaded.
3. Dont merge JS.

So anything above fold we need to make sure are of minimum size and preferably inline.
Images should have the resolution that is as per the device.

check your site speed score on GSI and check the payload specially for JS.

The second time page speed is because your browser has cached the assets so will not download those again.